# very loud fans when opening youtube video in full-screen mode

Tags: drivers, graphics, fan, amd-graphics

Today i installed ubuntu 16.04 lts on my laptop Fujitsu Lifebook a555g.
I have intel/amd hybrid in it.

Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500

ATI Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265]

As the title says, every time i open an yt video in fullscreen mode my fans start to work really loud.
Keep in mind that i'm total noob. It's my first encounter with linux.

Comment: Do you know if this happens with windows? I find it hard to believe that it is the OS issue.

Comment: No i don't know. This is a new laptop
Actually, after longer time the fans starts to work really loud even without full screen mode